# Why would entering an element with mouse button held down interfere with further mouse events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, addeventlistener, event-listener

On my [site in progress](http://www.cardtavern.com/), you can see a row of cards at the bottom. If you hover over them, it will show a larger version of that card. The larger version is draggable.

There's a strange edge case bug with this where *if you enter the row of cards with your mouse button held down as you enter, then release*, then try to click and drag-- dragging will not work.

I have set careful breakpoints and watched-- all the listeners are firing as normal, except that the onMouseMove listener that tracks the cursor for dragging *stops firing after you move roughly 2 pixels from where you were when you started the drag.* If you just move the cursor back and forth 1-2 pixels, it works. But as soon as you move more than that, the onMouseMove event stops firing altogether on that element. It starts firing again when you *release* the mouse. It's as though entering with the mouse down has inverted the events, yet it works normally within a 2px range of starting point.

I cannot think of any explanation for this behavior. Why would entering with the mouse button held down cause onMouseMove to stop firing if you moved more than 2 pixels from where you start the drag?

Additionally, when the attempted drag fails, this unfamiliar image appears next to the cursor until you release the button:

[image]

Can anyone identify this icon so I can look it up?

Comment: with 29K rep it is expected that SO will share the most relevant code

Comment: It's 300+ lines, it's a bit tough to share. I was hoping for conceptual suggestions related to known strangeness about interactions between mouseevents, I guess.

Comment: In Firefox 80 on macOS, I’m not seeing the buggy behavior you describe on the page you linked. What environment are you seeing the problem in?

Comment: Newest chrome on OS X. I have one additional clue. I will edit it in, one moment--

Comment: The icon that appears when dragging is just Chrome’s generic icon for a web page without a favicon. It’s the same icon Chrome puts in the tab of your page, next to the title. So the icon is not directly related to your problem – it’s not a “can’t drag” icon.

Comment: SOLVED--- added preventDefault on all event listeners. Don't fully understand it, but some reading will help with that. Thank you all for being rubber ducks though, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [OP’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63966659/why-would-entering-an-element-with-mouse-button-held-down-interfere-with-further#comment113113657_63966659), the solution was to call [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in all (drag-related?) event listeners.